# The live data updates function works on local but doesn't work on live? Socket.io + Node.js + Vue.js + AWS EC2

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, vue.js, amazon-ec2, socket.io

The code works properly on my local computer, but when it is uploaded on live server on AWS EC2, the connection is being refused.

We tried removing the security for testing purposes on AWS EC2, and the function now works.

So we thought it might be somewhere on the Security configuration of the AWS EC2 or on the code of the Node server, we're not entirely sure.

The security of the Node server port (8001), is only allowing 1 specific IP address, which is the IP Address of the site itself (samplehostname.com) that is trying to connect the Node server.

The security of the node server for request is we allow everything (for testing):

```
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
    res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', "*:*");
    res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods','GET');
    res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'Content-Type');
    next();
})
```

The error log is:

```
GET http://samplehostname.com:8001/socket.io/? 
EIO=3&transport=polling&t=MWnX8e4 net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED
```

Node.js Code:

```
var app = require('express')()
var server = require('http').Server(app)
var io = require('socket.io')(server)

app.use(function(req, res, next) {
    res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', "*:*");
    res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods','GET');
    res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'Content-Type');
    next();
})

io.on('connect', function (socket) {
  console.log(`Socket Connected ID: ${socket.id}`)
  var Redis = require('ioredis')
  var redis = new Redis({
    host: 'localhost',
    port: 1234,
    password: 'samplepasswordhere',

  })

  redis.subscribe('(CHANNEL-HERE)')

  redis.on("message", function (channel, message) {
    var parsed_message = JSON.parse(message)
    socket.emit(channel, parsed_message.data.data)
    console.log(message)
  })

})

var listener = server.listen(8001, ()=>{
    console.log('Node Server Listening on port ' + listener.address().port)
});
```

Vue.js Code:

```
 import io from 'socket.io-client'
 ...
 beforeCreate () {
    var socket = io(':8001', {secure: true})
    socket.on('(CHANNEL-HERE)', function (data) {

      vue.setPopulationData(JSON.parse(data))
    })
 }
 ...
```

Comment: If you have only your host authorized to connect, it won't work because connections to node are made from browser address not samplehostname.com.
It works on your local computer because every connection are local.
Good practice in your case, would be to use a reverse proxy (nginx does a great job)

Comment: Would it be alright to tell me more information? in how would it work, and in how i would i implement it?

Comment: You should find all you need here : https://www.nginx.com/blog/nginx-nodejs-websockets-socketio/

Comment: Alright I will look into it! Thanks for helping